# k -MST problem based on Miller-Tucker-Zemlin subtour elimination constraints

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, combinatorial-optimization

Where can I find the formulation of the $k$-MST ($k$-minimum spanning tree) problem as (mixed) integer linear program
based on Miller-Tucker-Zemlin subtour elimination constraints (MTZ)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the formulation that you are looking for:

> Min-degree constrained minimum spanning tree problem: New formulation
> via Miller–Tucker–Zemlin constraints

Source: http://yoksis.bilkent.edu.tr/pdf/files/10.1016-j.cor.2009.03.006.pdf

Comment: This is irrelevant.